# Flutter Getx Providers get fired twice

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, state-management

I'm using the `Getx` package to manage my app state,

there is something wired happening,

all the providers get initialized multiple times

this is my initialization method

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  ErrorWidget.builder = (e) => ErrorScreen(e.exception);

  await App.initializeProviders();
  if (Get.find<AuthProvider>().isAuth) await App.initializeUserProviders();


  runApp(const Appi());
}


class Appi extends StatelessWidget {
  const Appi({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

and these is the two methods that I use to initialise the providers

first core providers

```
static initializeProviders() async {
    try {
      Get.lazyPut<AuthProvider>(() => AuthProvider(), fenix: true);
      Get.lazyPut<SettingsProvider>(() => SettingsProvider(), fenix: true);
      Get.put<NotificationsProvider>(NotificationsProvider(), permanent: true);
      await Get.find<AuthProvider>().load();
      await Get.find<SettingsProvider>().load();
      await FirebasePlugin.initializeApp();
    } catch (e) {
      //
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

and second for the authenticated users

```
 static initializeUserProviders() async {
    try {
      Get.lazyPut<MainProvider>(() => MainProvider(), fenix: true);
      Get.lazyPut<FiltersProvider>(() => FiltersProvider(), fenix: true);
      Get.lazyPut<CartProvider>(() => CartProvider(), fenix: true);
      Get.lazyPut<SearchProvider>(() => SearchProvider(), fenix: true);
      // Get.lazyPut(() => HomeProvider(), fenix: true);
      // Get.find<HomeProvider>().load();
      Get.find<NotificationsProvider>().load();
      Get.find<FiltersProvider>().load();
      Get.find<CartProvider>().load();
    } catch (e) {
      //
    }
  }
```

and I got this in the debugging console

```
[GETX] Instance "NotificationsProvider" has been created
[GETX] Instance "NotificationsProvider" has been initialized
2[GETX] Instance "AuthProvider" has been created
2[GETX] Instance "AuthProvider" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "NotificationsProvider" has been created
[GETX] Instance "NotificationsProvider" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "AuthProvider" has been created
[GETX] Instance "AuthProvider" has been initialized
2[GETX] Instance "SettingsProvider" has been created
2[GETX] Instance "SettingsProvider" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "SettingsProvider" has been created
[GETX] Instance "SettingsProvider" has been initialized
2
W/FLTFireMsgService( 5927): Attempted to start a duplicate background isolate. Returning...
```

Note that I use exactly the same methods and the same way in another app and everything works there to find,

```
// auth load 

 Future<void> load() async {
    if (_profile.value != null && _token.value != null) return;
    final localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final lt1 = localStorage.getString('somekey1');
    final lt2 = localStorage.getString('somekey2');
    final lt3 = localStorage.getString('somekey3');
    final localProfile = localStorage.getString('_up');
    if (lt1 != null && lt2 != null && lt3 != null && localProfile != null) {
      _token.value = lt1 + lt2 + lt3;
      final profile = json.decode(localProfile);
      _profile.value = UserModel.fromJson(profile, avatar: profile['avatar']);
      update();
      return;
    }
  }






// filters load 
load() async {
    await App.getData('PRD/filters.php').then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        final platforms = value["brands"] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final stores = value["stores"] as Map<String, dynamic>;
        setFilters(stores.values.toList(), platforms.values.toList());
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      throw e;
      // TODO:: handle error
    });
  }

void setFilters(
    List<dynamic> stores,
    List<dynamic> platforms, {
    bool local = false,
  }) {
    if (stores.isEmpty || platforms.isEmpty) return;
    _allPlatforms.value.clear();
    _allStores.value.clear();
    _allPlatforms.value.add(Filter.getDefault(isPlatform: true));
    _allStores.value.add(Filter.getDefault());
    for (var platform in platforms) {
      _allPlatforms.value.add(Filter.fromJson(platform, isPlatform: true));
    }
    for (var store in stores) {
      _allStores.value.add(Filter.fromJson(store));
    }
    if (!local) {
      SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
        prefs.setString("allPlatforms", jsonEncode(platforms));
        prefs.setString("allStores", jsonEncode(stores));
      });
    }
    update();
  }








// notification load 
 Future<void> load() async {
    final result = await _database.getAll();
    if (result.length == _notifications.value.length) return;
    _notifications.value.clear();
    _notifications.value.addAll(result
        .map((e) => NotificationModel.fromJson({
              'id': e['id'],
              'message': e['title'],
              'type': e['type'],
              'type_id': e['type_id'],
              'level': e['level'],
              'is_new': e['is_new'],
            }))
        .toList());

    if (_notifications.value.isNotEmpty) {
      _notifications.value
          .sort((a, b) => int.parse(a.id).compareTo(int.parse(b.id)));
    }
    update();
  }




// cart load 
Future<void> load() async {
    try {
      final items = await database.getAll();
      _cartItems.clear();
      for (var e in items) {
        _cartItems.add(CartItem.fromJson(e));
      }
      update();
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: provide the load() methods code

Comment: and do those Get.lazyPut and Get.Put are the only ones executed in your entire app?

Comment: I added the load methods ,

Comment: yes,  Get.lazyPut and Get.Put only,  100% sure

Comment: It can be bugs realted code editor. Are you using vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue as following:

I create a new flutter project,
I move my lib folder to the new project.

I guess it was a bug in VSCode or something in the android folder.